# I want to make a program with embedded development board

Tags: embedded

I am studying about programming, so I want to make some programs.
Actuall, nowadays I'm studying embedded with embedded development board.
so, I want to make embedded program....
but...... I have no ideas...... what program I can make.
so could you guys recommend for me????

Comment: What board, what peripherals do you have?

Comment: It would help if you listed the specific board, if you have one in mind. You also might want to search for similar topics on the [electronics stack exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Here's a search from there for [embedded](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=embedded).

Answer (score 1):

The program you write will depend upon what hardware you have or what skills and equipment you have to build your hardware.

If you have no hardware (or electronics skills), then buy an off-the-shelf development board, and then the program will depend on the features available on the board.  The simplest will have no more than a serial or USB port and some I/O pins direct to the microcontroller's GPIO and peripheral device IO; you will need to attach additional hardware to this.  More expensive boards may include fast 32bit processors, displays, Ethernet, memory card interfaces, large external RAM/Flash memories, WiFi, buttons, switches, LED's etc.

At the very minimum if you have never brought an embedded system up before, you should do exactly what you might do on a desktop system when learning to program it; that is write "hello world".  In this case teh text should be emitted from the serial port, and displayed in a terminal emulator (such as TeraTerm or if you must, HyperTerminal).  This will confirm that you have the development tool-chain and work-flow working and can build an load the binary to the board.  It will also verify that you have basic serial host communications working which will be beneficial for debugging, especially if you do not have dedicated debug hardware such as a JTAG emulator or ICE.

You may find that your development tool suite, or the microcontroller or board vendor's website includes demonstration examples for your hardware which will include basic driver code.  No doubt there will be a simple serial I/O demonstration that will suit the "hello, world" test.  It may perform direct serial output, or it may be more sophisticated and provide library retargetting code such that standard I/O library calls such as printf() and getchar() will work over the serial port.

Once you have got the basics sorted, you are *then* perhaps ready to decide what to build.  If your board has a dot-matrix graphical display (even a very small one), and a few switches or a potentiometer, then a simple arcade game such as breakout, defender, invaders, or even pong would be possible and give instant gratification!

One of the most rewarding things you can do with an embedded system is make stuff move.  Motor control and robotics applications are most rewarding and have important *real-time* requirements that will develop skills that are not generally utilised on a desktop application.  For such applications you will need additional hardware to interface to high current devices such as motors, such as a simple H-Bridge controller.  You can purchase such hardware from a number of robotics kit suppliers, or you can build your own if you have the skills and equipment necessary.  I suggest starting with a simple "big-trak" style mobile vehicle (Meccano or Lego-Technic can be used if you have limited mechanical skills), and then perhaps add sensors such as bump-switches, light-detection, line follower, ultra-sonic, odometry etc.

When your applications ger more complex, you will benefit from learning about an deploying a simple RTOS or real-time scheduling kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Clock program. With a timezone converter.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at programming an Arduino ( http://www.arduino.cc ) or perhaps a MAKE controller of some sort ( http://www.makethings.com ). It really depends on what you want to do! Enjoy!

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/ also has various projects that rely on µControllers.  You'll have to do some browsing on that site, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `s3c6410` board may fit what you need [www.developmentboard.net](http://www.devleopmentboard.net) called `tenbyten6410`.I just bought it few days ago, now its working perfect in our project. I hope it will work in your project, as good as, in mine .